# Pandas to_datetime month read incorrectly

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have a data frame containing dates of the form YYYYMM (e.g. 201704).

Trying to transform it to a datetime type with:

```
data['ym'] = pd.to_datetime(data['ym'],format="%y%m")
data['year'], data['month'] = data['ym'].dt.year, data['ym'].dt.month
```

Gives me the correct years, but not the correct months:

```
 data['month'].unique()
```

returns only one value (and there are 12 in the data).

```
 data['ym']
```

returns

```
 2017-01-01 00:08:00
```

Any idea on how to correctly select the month as well?

Comment: Your Year-Month string is `"%Y%m"`

Comment: Thanks, @Rakesh! I have only tried "%Y%M".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%Y` to parse `YYYY`, `%y` is for `YY` years format:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'ym':['201704','201705','201706']})

data['ym'] = pd.to_datetime(data['ym'], format="%Y%m")
data['year'], data['month'] = data['ym'].dt.year, data['ym'].dt.month
print (data)
          ym  year  month
0 2017-04-01  2017      4
1 2017-05-01  2017      5
2 2017-06-01  2017      6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with python's datetime module:

```
from datetime import datetime
data['ym'] = data['ym'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), format='%Y%m'))
```